# How to migrate android app to ios (easy way?)

Tags: android, ios, migration

I have some years experience as Java (specially) and Android developer, and I have an interesting Android app with more tan 10k downloads, so I am thinking to move app also to iOS, but I don´t know neither Objective C nor iOS programming in general (I have been making research but it seems hard...

Is there any easy way (don´t suggest Phonegap because it has some complicated logic behind)
to make an iOS app from my ANDROID SOURCE CODE?

Comment: If you can program in Java, you can program in Objective-C. I recommend following the Stanford CS193p iOS course on iTunesU called `Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad`. It will take you through building up an app and show you a small portion of the available frameworks. Then you can attempt to port your code and come back with any specific problems you may have.

Answer (score 1):

I could try to use [Java2ObjC](https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/). This tool could migrate Java code to Objective C. But this tool doesn't migrate UI, it is only for logic. It means that all UI related code you have to write manually.